# Windows 7 gust in VirtualBox dead slow, on windows 10 host

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox

I added win7 image as disk in VirtualBox and when I start it, first screen loads normal:

[image: "First screen"]

but after that this "Starting Windows" screen loads literally frame by frame, and it doesn't finish:

[image: Second screen]
[image: Second screen after 1 minute]

Here are my VirtualBox settings:

[image: my VirtualBox settings]

Here is my system info:

[image: my system info]

NOTE: I tried to install it in VMware and it works

Comment: "I tried to install it in VMware and it works"  <-- Is the image a VBOX Image?   I have Windows 7 installed and running in VMware as well and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you may want to disable the `3D Acceleration`. It causes damaged more than you've.

Second, reduce your `Video Memory` from *256* to *128*.